# Java keycode 194, what key is that?

Tags: java

My teacher gave me a challenge:

He told me to write a Java program which captured keys typed, and return their key code, and say what he pressed.

My problem is that he somehow typed the following sequence:

```
194 131 194 130 194 135
```

I have no idea how to reproduce this! There is no key with the code 194, and this is strange because he said he used the num-pad, but even so I can't find a way to do this. Any help?

Edit:
Here is the code

```
public void nativeKeyPressed(NativeKeyEvent e)
{
    System.out.println(NativeKeyEvent.getKeyText(131)+" "+NativeKeyEvent.getKeyText(130)+" "+NativeKeyEvent.getKeyText(135));
    //17 = ctrl
    //18 = alt
    //113 = F2
    //32 = space
    if (!writingSupressed) ///DACA NU O BAGAT CODU ALA
    {
        if (checkCode(e.getKeyCode())) //DACA CODUL A FOST INTRODUS
        {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    KiraUtils.dialog("Hello, you are protected.");
                }
            }).start();
            writingSupressed=true;
            ClientMode.dm.cleanBuffer();
        }

        if (Character.isLetter((char)e.getKeyCode()))
        {
            if (isCaps)
            {
                ClientMode.dm.log(e.getKeyCode());
            }
            else
            {
                ClientMode.dm.log(e.getKeyCode()+32);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            if (e.getKeyCode()==20)
            {
                if (!capsPressed)
                {
                    capsPressed=true;
                    isCaps=!isCaps;
                    ClientMode.dm.log(20);
                }
            }
            else
            if (e.getKeyCode()==17)
            {
                if (!ctrlPressed)
                {
                    ctrlPressed=true;
                    ClientMode.dm.log(17);
                }
            }
            else if (e.getKeyCode()==16)
            {
                if (!shiftPressed)
                {
                    shiftPressed=true;
                    isCaps=!isCaps;
                    ClientMode.dm.log(16);
                }
            }
            else if (e.getKeyCode()==18)
            {
                if (!altPressed)
                {
                    altPressed=true;
                    ClientMode.dm.log(18);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ClientMode.dm.log(e.getKeyCode());
            }
        }

    }
    else //DACA O BAGAT CODU ALA
    {
        if (checkCode(e.getKeyCode()))
        {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    KiraUtils.dialog("You are no longer protected.");
                }
            }).start();
            writingSupressed=false;
        }
    }
}
```

But pressing Alt+194 will output 18 (alt) and then the ascii codes for 1, 9 and 4

Comment: Try this: Press Alt, strike 1, strike 9. strike 4, release alt. All numbers must be pressed on numpad.

Comment: ┬ Hi, i'm the symbol

Comment: @pzaenger I am not sure that Java and Javascript use the same keycodes.

Comment: Those are the secret teacher codes you learn in teaching college.

Comment: Note that ASCII only defines characters up to 127 decimal, and [Unicode](http://unicode-table.com/en/) defines the characters above that.  Although in certain contexts other "code pages" may be mapped into the characters 128-255.

Comment: (In certain contexts you can enter a Unicode code value by doing Alt-digit-digit-digit on the numeric pad.)

Comment: Added the code, and Alt+194 will just print the codes for Alt, for 1, for 9 and for 4. Sooo this is not it :(

Comment: Try alt + 0194 with the numpad

Comment: Any other keys will simply be printed as they are, so regardless of what Alt+Number i press, the output will be the code for Alt followed by the code of each digit of the following number :(

Comment: Have you tried the extended keys (calculator, PC, mail,home) (if you have them).

Comment: Nope, he did it with a basic keyboard. I thought 194 was the "AltGr" keycode, but I don't have an AltGr key :/ I thought so because 131, 130, 135 appear to be "Dead keys" as shown by this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode , and 194 seems to be NumpadComma (this is actually right, the keyboard is set to have the dot as a comma) but 130 and 135 and so on still make no sense to me :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java is UTF-8 so 194 131 is UTF-8 micro sign (funky u), 194 130 is acute accent, 194 135 is capital letter c with cedilla.

Source:
http://www.utf8-chartable.de/

to type micro sign
Alt 0181
Alt 230

Comment: Will give it a go asap, hope this one would be it

Comment: Got it somehow else, by changing the keyboard layout! Haha, that was tricky! Thanks for guiding me into UTF-8 though, that gave me the idea